# SwiftUI Add top line to TabBar

Tags: colors, line, swiftui, tabbar

How can I add a line/divider on the top of my TabBar for adding some kind of a splitter between my view and TabBar?

Comment: What's wrong with standard TabBar divider?

Comment: My TabBar in SwifUI is just white.

Comment: On device? Simulator? Preview? I have Xcode 11.2 and it is everywhere like regular, eg. of [screenshot](https://static.wixstatic.com/media/5feefe_9a2c78b763f74d7eac956b10d1312962~mv2_d_2208_1242_s_2.jpg/v1/fill/w_940,h_529,al_c,q_90,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/5feefe_9a2c78b763f74d7eac956b10d1312962~mv2_d_2208_1242_s_2.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot that I have added this code for making the TabBar completely white.
But my shadow color was white, so I just changed it to Gray

```
extension UITabBarController {
override open func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()

    appearance.backgroundColor = .white
    appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
    appearance.shadowColor = .gray

    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .black
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]

    self.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the previous answer didn't work for me, iOS 17.2
This one works:

```
func setupTabBarAppearance() {
    let standardAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()

    standardAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    standardAppearance.shadowColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.3)

    UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = standardAppearance
    UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = standardAppearance
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can change color of TabBar line

```
init(){
  UITabBar.appearance().separatorColor = .red
  UITabBar.appearance().separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

Comment: `separatorColor` , `separatorInset` does not exist for the appearance proxy of UITabBar.